# vc++ 2010 and microsoft.office.interop.excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have been able to use Visual Basic 2010 and microsoft.office.interop.excel to read from and write to xls files.
However, the result, as a whole, is slow and not very elegant a solution. so I decided to start from scratch and use Visual C++ 2010 this time though now I am at a loss at how to approach the interop aspect of the project in vc++ 2010.
Specifically, I have installed the office primary assembelies for office 2003, 2007 and 2010 but cant seem to find a way to reference the assembalies in the IDE.
Does anyone know of an idiots guide that could help, all that I have been able to find relate to VB, C# or an earlier version of Visual c++ and I would like to be able to doe this in c++/Cli.
Any help that would get me going in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really think that C++/CLI will be faster than VB .NET making the same work?

Comment: not specifically, but part of a more thought out and contained solution, yes. I found this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10886/How-to-use-Managed-C-to-Automate-Excel but as it relates to a previous version of visual studio it is of little use to get me started.

Comment: It is *not* going to be any faster.  Right-click the project, Properties, Common Properties, click the Add New Reference button.  Doubtful you'll enjoy the missing IntelliSense support in VS2010.

Comment: Thanks Hans with your tip I managed to move forward so thank V.much :)